# how to select and average rows in a table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data consists of 1024 rows.
I want to average rows as (1,2,3) (4,5,6) (7,8,9) etc.  Is it possible in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You mean to say, you want to calculate average in groups of 3 rows?

Comment: Yes i want to calculate average in group of 3 rows in the same table

Comment: Can you provide the skeleton schema of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your input, you seem to be looking for following query:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(a AS float)) avga, AVG(CAST(b AS float)) avgb, AVG(CAST(c AS float)) avgc FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY null) - 1 rn, *
FROM tab) t
GROUP BY (rn/3)
ORDER BY rn/3
```

let me know if it worked.

Here is the query at SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0f524/5

Comment: i want to calculate average of first three rows and next three rows and next three and soon in the same table

Comment: Ok fine, I'll give it a try

Comment: do you also want to order the rows based on some column and then take average of sets of three row?

Comment: @DipenduPaul Does this give the required output?

Comment: ERROR:  function avg(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AVG(wavelength) avga, AVG(reflectance) avgb FROM
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function avg(text) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 8

Comment: It shows the error in PostgreSQL. Function doesn't exist

Comment: I guess the column you try to take average, is of type text. It should be type casted to numeric type and then avg needs to be applied

Comment: @AbishekArumugam: please do ***NOT*** edit an answer to ask for clarification or to add error message that *you* get when running the solution. The error message is pretty clear though: you are trying to use `avg()` on a character column. The average can only be calculated on numbers, not strings.

Comment: How text type should be type casted to numeric type in postgresql

Comment: My column is of type text.How it should type cast to numeric type

Comment: Have a look at the query, I have used CAST function to convert text to float

Comment: In the sample shown in SQL Fiddle, I have taken the field type as text. Follow the SQL Fiddle link and it should be clear.

Comment: @AbishekArumugam: why do you store numbers in a `text` column. If those are numbers they should be stored in an `integer` or `numeric` column, never as strings.